# Elm: clear form on submit

Tags: elm

I have a simple form with one field. I would like to clear the field on form submit. I am clearing my model in my update function, but text remains in the text input.

```
type alias Model =
    { currentSpelling : String }

type Msg
    = MorePlease

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        MorePlease ->
            (  log "cleared spelling: " { model | currentSpelling = "" }
                , fetchWord model.currentSpelling )

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ Html.form [ onSubmit MorePlease ]
            [ input [ type' "text"
                    , placeholder "Search for your word here"
                    , onInput NewSpelling
                    , attribute "autofocus" ""
                    ] []
            , text model.currentSpelling
            , input [ type' "submit" ] [ text "submit!" ]
            ]
        ]
```

The `text` displaying `model.currentSpelling` clears out when I empty it with the update function, but the text input box remains populated. Any idea how to clear it?

`fetchWord` makes an HTTP call, but it's omitted here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

add `value model.currentSpelling` into Attributes of the
input element.  That's how you can control the string
inside of input element in html.

Comment: fantastic! `Html.Attributes.value` is just what I needed!

Comment: Be aware that `Html.Attributes.value` suffers from a bug, that leads to a "jumping cursor" when typing quickly while the cursor is not positioned after the last character in the field.

See the bug in action here: https://runelm.io/c/wdr and a thread about the issue here: https://github.com/elm-lang/html/issues/105

Comment: It took me a while to figure out that the view is "refreshed" every time the value of currentSpelling would be updated.  This means that currentSpelling is not "bound" to the value, instead the value being displayed is constantly updating because the view is updating.